# PigLatin Issue with substr() and slice()

Tags: javascript, slice, substr

**OBJECTIVE**
Given a string, translate the string into PigLatin (if the string starts with a vowel, append "way" to end of string - else look for the first vowel and take all preceding letters and place on the end of str, add "ay").

**CODE**

```
function translate(str) {

    //list vowels
    var vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

    //if first letter = vowel, add 'way' to end of sentence
    // else return all letters before first vowel and append to end (with 'ay')
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (vowel.indexOf(str[0]) > -1) {
            return str + 'way';
        } else {
          return str.substr(i+1) + str.slice(0,i+1) + 'ay';
        }
    }
}




translate("dresser");
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. The aforementioned code works for cases such as "algorithm" and "desk", but failed with "glove" - leading me to believe the problem is around .substr() or .slice(). Additional investigation believes this is a logic error. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your code will always return from the loop during the first iteration. `i` will never be greater than 0.

What you should do (for starters) is remove the check from inside the loop. Like this:

```
function translate(str) {

    //list vowels
    var vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];
    //if first letter = vowel, add 'way' to end of sentence
    if (vowel.indexOf(str[0]) > -1) {
        return str + 'way';
    }

    // else return all letters before first vowel and append to end (with 'ay')
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (vowel.indexOf(str[i]) > -1) {
            return str.substr(i) + str.slice(0,i) + 'ay';
        }
    }
}
```

This code should do the trick.

Comment: hmmmm... Can you please ellaborate?
Do I need to use a 'break' statement when vowel.indexOf(str[i]) > -1?

Comment: @kidlogic No, no break statement. You were unconditionally returning from the loop too early. I updated my answer with code that works. I took out the `i+1`'s and replaced them with `i`'s.

Comment: that you for this - I feel silly as I recently had very similar code but then thought I was being redundant with my vowel.indexOf(str[i]) >-1 


Thanks!

Comment: @kidlogic ymway easureplay

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a value without testing if the character is a vowel.

```
function translate(str) {

    //list vowels
    var vowel = ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u'];

    //if first letter = vowel, add 'way' to end of sentence
    // else return all letters before first vowel and append to end (with 'ay')
    for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        if (vowel.indexOf(str[0]) > -1) {
            return str + 'way';
        } else if(vowel.indexOf(str[i]) !== -1) {
          return str.substr(i) + str.slice(0,i) + 'ay';
        }
    }
}
```

Note how I added the `if` to test if the character is a vowel.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0trqt383/)